# Pandas bar plot with continuous x axis

Tags: pandas

I try to make a barchart in pandas, with two data series coming from a groupby:

```
data.groupby(['popup','UID']).size().groupby(level=0).value_counts().unstack().transpose().plot(kind='bar', layout=(2,2))
```

The x axis is not continuous, and only shows values that are in the dataset. In this example, it jumps from 11 to 13.

How can I make it continuous?

[image: BarChart]

**EDIT 2: **

I tried JohnE datacentric approach, and it works. It creates a new index with no missing values:

```
temp = data.groupby(['popup','UID']).size().groupby(level=0).value_counts().unstack().transpose()
temp.reindex(np.arange(temp.index.min(), temp.index.max())).plot(kind='bar', layout=(2,2))
```

[image: Result]

However, I assume there should be a better approach with histogram instead of bar plot. The best I could do with histograms is:

```
data.groupby(['popup','UID']).size().groupby(level=0).plot(kind='hist', bins=30, alpha=0.5, layout=(2,2), legend=True)
```

[image: Result]

But I didn't find any option in hist plot to get the same rendering than bar plot, without bar overlapping.

**EDIT: ** Here are some information to answer comments.

Data sample:

```
     INSEE   C1  popup   C3                  date  \
0  75101.0  0.0      0  NaN  2017-05-17T13:20:16Z   
0  75101.0  0.0      0  NaN  2017-05-17T14:23:51Z   
1  31557.0  0.0      1  NaN  2017-05-17T14:58:27Z   

                                    UID
0  ba4bd353-f14d-4bc5-95ba-6a1f5134cc84   
0  ba4bd353-f14d-4bc5-95ba-6a1f5134cc84   
1  bafe9715-3a07-4d9b-b85c-0bbf658a9115
```

First groupby result (sample):

```
data.groupby(['popup','UID']).size().head(3)
popup  UID                                 
0      016d3e7e-1901-4f84-be0e-117988ec57a8    6
       01c15455-29cc-4d1e-8743-638fd0f51602    6
       03fc9eb0-c5fb-4205-91f0-4b74f78a8b96    3
dtype: int64
```

Second groupby result (sample):

```
data.groupby(['popup','UID']).size().groupby(level=0).value_counts().head(3)
popup   
0      1    46
       3    23
       4    22
dtype: int64
```

After unstack and transpose:

```
data.groupby(['popup','UID']).size().groupby(level=0).value_counts().unstack().transpose().head(3)
```

```
popup     0     1
1      46.0  38.0
2      21.0  35.0
3      23.0  22.0
```

Comment: Can you post sample data? Also what does groupby output look like?

Comment: I dunno about plot options, but you could take a data-centric approach and just reindex with all the values you want on the x-axis.  Maybe with a fillna also?  e.g. `df.reindex(range(30)).fillna(0)`

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution with histogram plot from matplotlib.axes.Axes.hist. It is better to use histograms than bar plots for this purpose, as we can choose the number of bins.

```
# Separate groups by 'popup' and count number of records for each 'UID'
popup_values = data['popup'].unique()
count_by_popup = [data[data['popup'] == popup_value].groupby(['UID']).size() for popup_value in popup_values]

# Create histogram
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.hist(count_by_popup, 20, histtype='bar', label=[str(x) for x in popup_values])
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```